# Double variable in print function possible matrix operation

Tags: python, list, matrix

I have a simple list stated as a non-matrix. The print function calls on the variable in two manners than a location. I am unable to find materials explaining why the answer rendered is rendered when ran. I would like a walk through if possible so I can understand.

I've tried to look the solution up though I may be using improper keywords.

```
lst=[3,1,-2]
print(lst[lst[-1]])
```

I understand its a list with the variable lst containing 3,1,-2 in the 0,1,2 location left to right or -1,-2,-3 location right to left. What does the lst in brackets do that causes the answer to be 1 instead of -2?

Comment: Your understanding about `list` indices is right. Analyze your print statement in steps by step. You will get your answer. Happy learning.

Answer (score 1):

The term lst[-1] returns -2 and now when this passed again to lst, like lst[-2] it returns second last element that is 1, if you want -2 as your answer just do `print(lst[-1])`

Comment: This makes sense thank you very much. This is one of the practice questions I missed while studying for my python cert. Could not figure out why.